# VCL App Deploying with runtime libraries....how to link to 32 bit vs 64 bit?

Tags: dll, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-10-seattle

I have a Win 7 64bit system that I deploy VCL apps to.

I have both 64bit VCL and 32bit VCL applications running on that system.

The 64bit application has been built in C++ Builder 10.0 Seattle and runs fine.

The 32bit application is being upgraded to Seattle, and that's where the confusion comes in.  I was getting an error on not able to find a wrapper in the borlndmm.dll.  I updated the DLL in both the System32 and SySWOW64 directories from the C++Builder's Win32 and Win64 redist folders.  I am now getting the error "application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b".  It looks like the 32bit application is linking to the 64bit DLL.

How can I have 64bit and 32bit VCL applications co-exist on the same system and link to their respecitve DLLs correctly?  How do I correct this?

I wish I could compile the 32bit application to not require borlndmm.dll, but even with the "Link with Dynamic RTL" and "Link with runtime packages" options disabled, I get an error on linking with borlndmm.dll.

Comment: If you put the 64bit DLL in the System32 folder, and the 32bit DLL in the SysWOW64 folder, there is no way a 32bit app can be loading the 64bit DLL, unless it is loading it from another folder. Check the target machine to see if there are other copies of the DLL.  Or, just put the DLLs in the app folder instead of system folders.  That being said, if you want to compile a self-contained EXE, make sure you also disable the linker's "Link with the Delphi Runtime Library" option as well.

Comment: I did the opposite - 64 bit in the SysWOW64 dir and 32 bit file in the System32.  Is that wrong?  I always thought the SysWOW64 directory was for 64 bit files.  The "Link with the Delphi Runtime Library" option is false as well which I thought made it very strange that the binary was still requiring the borlndmm.dll.  Thanks for the help Remy - I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, that is wrong.  On a 64bit system, the System32 folder is for 64bit files only, and the SysWOW64 folder is for 32bit files only.  WOW64 is a 32bit emulator, not a 64bit emulator.  If your app is dependent on a DLL despite the project settings, then you have to be static linking to a library that itself has a dependency on the DLL.